# when clicked on a row in grid after sorting, the row is reverted to original position

Tags: reactjs, sorting

I have to sort my grid. Then if I click on a row , it's details should be obtained.

Now,

I sorted my table. Then if try try to click on a row(after sorting one column) the position of that row is changing(reverting to it's orginal position,ie. to unsorted position).

This happens only when sorting is applied to the grid.

This is the code:

```
class DashboardAddPrintLetterStep4 extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={
            orderby: '',
            order: {},
            insurance: props.insurance && props.insurance,
        }
        this.sort = this.sort.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {       
        if(this.state.insurance != nextProps.insurance)
        {
            this.setState({
                insurance: nextProps.insurance && nextProps.insurance
            });
        }
    }

    sort(event){
        const {order} =this.state;
        let { insurance} = this.props;
        order[event.target.id]=! order[event.target.id];
        insurance= _.orderBy(insurance, (o)=> typeof o[event.target.id] === 'string' ? o[event.target.id].trim().toLowerCase() : o[event.target.id], order[event.target.id] ? 'asc' : 'desc');
        this.setState({
            orderby: event.target.id,
            insurance,
            order
        });
    }

    render() {
        const { selectedIns, onSelectInsurance } = this.props;
        const {insurance, order} = this.state;

        return (
            <div >
                    <table >
                        <thead >
                            <tr >
                                <th id='Company'  onClick={this.sort}>Insurance Company {order.Company?<i className="fa fa-sort-asc"/> : <i className="fa fa-sort-desc"/>}</th>
                                <th id='Verified' onClick={this.sort}>Verified {order.Verified?<i className="fa fa-sort-asc"/> : <i className="fa fa-sort-desc"/>}</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody >
                            {insurance && insurance.map(insuranceItem =>
                                <tr key={insuranceItem.InsID} \}
                                    onClick={ () => onSelectInsurance(insuranceItem) }

                                    >
                                    <td  title={insuranceItem.Company ? insuranceItem.Company : insuranceItem.TempInsurance} >{insuranceItem.Company ? insuranceItem.Company : insuranceItem.TempInsurance}</td>
                                    <td >
                                        {insuranceItem.Verified === 1 ? 'Yes' : 'No'}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            )}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        insurance: state.patientDetailsReducer.patientDetails.PatientInsuranceModel.Insurance,
        selectedIns: state.printLetterReducer.selectedIns,
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onSelectInsurance: Insurance => {
            dispatch(selectInsurance(Insurance));
        }
    };
};

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(DashboardAddPrintLetterStep4);
```

Eg: 1.(Data before sorting)

Nokia

Samsung

Apple

2. After sort

Apple

Nokia

Samsung

3. then I clicked the row 'Nokia' .The issue is the table revert to it's original position like in Step 1 ie.,

Nokia

Samsung

Apple

How can I solve this, to make the row fixed in the same position after sort ?

Comment: It's a bit hard to say without knowing what your `selectInsurance` does. I am a bit curious why the selectInsurance would be a dispatch, while the rest of your actions on the data represent a local state

Comment: I think your dispatch command retrieves data which updates `insurance` in state. So the updated `insurance` is not a sorted one in the state.

Comment: just a comment, you are not providing a default value `insurance: props.insurance && props.insurance,`

Comment: One suggestion is, if you have `orderBy` in state in `componentWillReceiveProps` method, sort the `insurance`.